# How do I remove 'www.' from all internal links in self-hosted multisite?

Tags: multisite, links, subdomains

This is my first WP administration (I have inherited this from another developer), so I would appreciate it if you could treat me as a newbie.

I have a site with 40 or so pages and all the links on any page, image etc. are pointing at //www.mydomain.com, but I want them to point at //mydomain.com.  The home page redirects clients correctly already (I believe this is a normal WP behaviour, as they think it is best practice and I am happy with that), but since the WP editor automatically creates links with the www subdomain, it's flicking back and forth between both as the user goes into the site.

I don't want to do a re-direct with the .htaccess file as that creates overhead (and this is a work-around, not the desired behaviour), but there are far too many to change manually, and I suspect that any new ones would also be created with the www prefix anyway..  So how do I change this behaviour as well as changing the existing links?

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as going to Settings > General and ensuring that the values for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) do not have 'www' in the textbox.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already tried this (they're in a different place under multisite installs, BTW).

Comment: Ok - I didn't see the multisite tag before and it wasn't mentioned in the question. I assume there's no redirect plugins installed?

Comment: No, no plugins doing anything like it (there are some, but they are not related, I've had a good look).

Comment: A hack could be to check for www in the URL and then do a wp_redirect() to the correct URL but there must be something else causing this. I have to state that I have never used Multisite though.